# Adding minutes to the time represented by the object

Tags: java

I need to write a method to add minutes to a time that represented by the object I created.
I cannot import calendar or similar, and if the giving num is negative it will be subtracted from the object time.
additionally, the range of given time have to stay between 0-23 for hours and 0-59 for minutes.

what am I doing wrong?

````
{
  Time1 time = new Time1(_hour, _minute);
  Time1 time2 = new Time1(time);
  if (num < 0 && _hour>23)
   {
   time2._hour = (_hour*60+_minute/60+num)/60;
   return time2;
   }
   else if (_hour < 23)
   {
    int temp;
   temp = (time2._hour*60+time2._minute)+num; 
   time2._hour = temp/60; 
   time2._minute = temp%60; 
   return time2;
    }
    else
   {
    int temp1;
    temp1=(time2._hour*60+time2._minute)+num;
    time2._hour= temp1/60; //1
    time2._minute= temp1%60; //40
   return time2;
   }```



*my output from the tester:*

Testing addMinutes method:

enter code here
    t1=11:25
    Adding 10 minutes to t1=11:35
    Adding 20 minutes to **23:45= 24:05** 
    Adding 48 hours and -5 min to 23:45= **71:40**
    Adding 48 hours and +5 min to 23:45= **71:50**
    Adding 48 hours to **23:45= 71:45**
    Adding -48 hours to **23:45= 0-24:0-15**
    Adding -48 hours to **23:45= 0-24:0-15**
    Adding -10 minutes to **00:05= 00:0-5**
    Adding -48 hours and -6 min to **00:05= 0-48:0-1**
    Adding -48 hours and +6 min to 0**0:05= 0-47:0-49**
````

Comment: Somewhere I think you should be doing `hour = hour % 24` after adding the hours.  Including the Time class and the test code would help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also, how should your class react when you add minutes and hours, which will result in a value greater than 23:59? Do you have fields for "days" and "years" as well?